# Basic network layer for a JSON API client

Tags: beginner, json, swift, http

Just looking for some feedback/ways to improve this basic networking layer written in Swift. I'm still learning, please elaborate with as much detail as possible.

```
enum HTTPMethod: String {
    case get = "GET"
}

 class HTTPLayer {

     let baseURL = URL(string: "https://example.com")!

     func request(at endpoint: Endpoint, completion: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let url = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(endpoint.path)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            completion(data, error)
        }
        task.resume()
    }

 }

 enum Endpoint {

     case listTransactions
    case transactionDetails(String)

     var method: HTTPMethod {
        return .get
    }

     var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .listTransactions:
            return "/api/transactions/"
        case .transactionDetails(let id):
            return "/api/transactions/id"
        }
    }

 }

 struct Transaction: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let amount: Double
}

 struct TransactionDetails: Decodable {
    let payload: [String: String]
}

 enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(NSError)
}

 class APIClient {

     let httpLayer: HTTPLayer
    init(httpLayer: HTTPLayer) {
        self.httpLayer = httpLayer
    }

     func transactions(completion: @escaping (Result<[Transaction]>) -> Void) {
        self.httpLayer.request(at: .listTransactions) { (data, error) in
            if error != nil {
                completion(.failure(error! as NSError))
            } else {
                do {
                    let transactions = try JSONDecoder().decode([Transaction].self, from: data!)
                    completion(.success(transactions))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(self.defaultError))
                }
            }
        }
    }

     func transactionDetails(for transaction: Transaction, completion: @escaping (Result<TransactionDetails>) -> Void) {
        self.httpLayer.request(at: .transactionDetails(transaction.id)) { (data, error) in
            if error != nil {
                completion(.failure(error! as NSError))
            } else {
                do {
                    let transactions = try JSONDecoder().decode(TransactionDetails.self, from: data!)
                    completion(.success(transactions))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(self.defaultError))
                }
            }
        }
    }

     var defaultError: NSError = NSError(domain: "", code: 1, userInfo: nil)

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few things that can be improved, will start with the major ones:

**General**

- Instead of having function for each API call you can generalise it a bit like so:

```
/* Updated the name, since it's not only for transactions anymore
Since we no longer know the exact endpoint we will have to pass it to the function

I would also add `requestMeta` parameter that will contain any other information that would be needed to perform the api call
`parameters`, `encoding`, `authenticationType`, `additionalHeaders`, `shouldReauthenticate`
but this is in case you need them
*/

func apiReques<T: Codable>(_ dataType: T.Type,
                                    endpoint: Endpoint,
                                  completion: @escaping (Result<[T], ResultError>) -> Void) {

        self.httpLayer.request(at: endpoint) { (data, error) in

// In general an "early return" strategy is preferred, use guard when applicable and avoid nesting `if` statements
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }

// Do not force unwrap, it's better to show empty screen (or error) instead of crashing the app
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(.failure(NSError(domain: "", code: 1, userInfo: [:])))
                return
            }

            do {
                let transactions = try JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data)
                completion(.success(transactions))
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(self.defaultError))
            }
        }
    }
```

So, since your structures are `Decodable` (consider using `Codable`) you can easily use generics.

The `_ dataType: T.Type` is a bit tricky. Since we are not returning `T` we have to add it as a parameter so the compiler can infer the actual type (more on the topic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965439/cannot-explicitly-specialize-a-generic-function)

- I would prefer keeping all the urls in one place, so I would move `baseURL` to endpoints enum. Again do not force unwrap

```
enum Endpoint {

    static let baseURLString = "https://example.com"

    case listTransactions
    case transactionDetails(String)
}

extension Endpoint {

    var method: HTTPMethod {
        return .get
    }

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .listTransactions:
            return Endpoint.baseURLString + "/api/transactions/"
        case .transactionDetails(let id):
            return Endpoint.baseURLString + "/api/transactions/\(id)"
        }
    }
}
```

This will affect your `request` func:

```
func request(at endpoint: Endpoint, completion: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) {

        guard let url = URL(string: endpoint.path) else { return }
// endpoint.method is available as well if needed

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            completion(data, error)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

- It seems that you are instantiating new `HTTPLayer` for every `APIClient`. In that case I would just go with `private let httpLayer: HTTPLayer = HTTPLayer()` and deleting the `init`. In that case you can mark `class HTTPLayer` as `fileprivate` so noone beside `APIClient` can access it and if any params needs to be passed to it will go through `APIClient` -> `apiReques()`

**Error handling**

- If you want to go a bit further you can update the `enum Result`

```
enum Result<Value, Error: Swift.Error> {
    case success(Value)
    case failure(Error)
}
```

and also adding your custom errors:

```
enum ResultError: Error {
    case general(String?)
    case specific(Int?)
    case `default` // default is a keyword so if you want to use it, you should wrap it in ``, imo don't and choose another name
    case whateverYouWant
}

extension ResultError {
    var errorString: String {
        switch self {
...
        }
    }

    private func specificErrorString(_ errorCode: Int) -> String {
        switch errorCode {
...
        }
    }
}
```

This will affect the generic `apiRequest` a bit in the signature `@escaping (Result<[T], ResultError>) -> Void)` and ofc the `completions`

```
completion(.failure(.general("something went wrong")))
completion(.failure(.specific(123))
completion(.failure(.default)
```

Now you can delete `var defaultError: NSError = NSError(domain: "", code: 1, userInfo: nil)`

**How to use it**

```
APIClient(). apiReques(Transaction.self,endpoint: Endpoint.listTransactions) { data in

    switch data {
    case .success(let response):
        print("Success")
    case .failure(let error):
        print("error")
    }
}
```

**Bonus**

You can also split the completion into two completion `success` and `failure`

- Signature

```
func apiReques <T: Decodable>(_ dataType: T.Type,
                                    endpoint: Endpoint,
                                    success: @escaping (([T]) -> Void),
                                    failure: @escaping ((ResultError) -> Void))
```

- block calls

```
failure(.general(""))
failure(.default)
success(data)
```

- Usage

```
APIClient().transactions(Transaction.self,
                         endpoint: Endpoint.listTransactions,
                         success: { data in
                            print(data)
}, failure: { error in
    print(error)
})
```